# Can anyone tell me how to convert UTF-8 value to UCS-2 value in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, utf-8, ucs2

I am trying to convert UTF-8 string into UCS-2 string.
I need to get string like "\uFF0D\uFF0D\u6211\u7684\u4E0A\u7F51\u4E3B\u9875".
I have googled for about a month by now, but still there is no reference about converting UTF-8 to UCS-2.
Please someone help me.
Thx in advance.

EDIT: okay, maybe my explanation was not good enough. Here is what I am trying to do.
I live in Korea, and I am trying to send a sms message using CTMessageCenter. I tried to send chinese simplified character through my app. And I get ???? Instead of proper characters. So I tried UTF-8, UTF-16, BE and LE as well. But they all return ??. Finally I found out that SMS uses UCS-2 and EUC-KR encoding in Korea. Weird, isn't it?
Anyway I tried to send string like \u4E3B\u9875 and it worked.
So I need to convert string into UCS-2 encoding first and get the string literal from those strings.

Comment: "\uFF0D\uFF0D\u6211\u7684\u4E0A\u7F51\u4E3B\u9875" is not a UCS-2 string. Rather it's a C or Objective-C string literal using the `\u` escape sequence to include characters specified by their Unicode code point. Do you really need UCS-2 or a string literal?

Comment: I need UCS-2 encoding and its string literal.

Comment: UCS-2 is essentially the same as UTF-16.

Comment: And, of course, the characters in an Objective-C string are UTF-16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2):

> The older UCS-2 (2-byte Universal Character Set) is a similar
>   character encoding that was superseded by UTF-16 in version 2.0 of the
>   Unicode standard in July 1996.[2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2928/index.htm?info/nls/rbagsucs2.htm)  It produces a fixed-length format
>   by simply using the code point as the 16-bit code unit and produces
>   exactly the same result as UTF-16 for 96.9% of all the code points in
>   the range 0-0xFFFF, including all characters that had been assigned a
>   value at that time.

[IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2928/index.htm?info/nls/rbagsucs2.htm):

> Since the UCS-2 standard is limited to 65,535 characters, and the data
>   processing industry needs over 94,000 characters, the UCS-2 standard
>   is in the process of being superseded by the Unicode UTF-16 standard.
>
> However, because UTF-16 is a superset of the existing UCS-2 standard,
>   you can develop your applications using the systems existing UCS-2
>   support as long as your applications treat the UCS-2 as if it were
>   UTF-16.

[uincode.org](http://unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#14):

> UCS-2 is obsolete terminology which refers to a Unicode
>   implementation up to Unicode 1.1, before surrogate code points and
>   UTF-16 were added to Version 2.0 of the standard. This term should now
>   be avoided.
>
> UCS-2 does not define a distinct data format, because UTF-16 and UCS-2
>   are identical for purposes of data exchange. Both are 16-bit, and have
>   exactly the same code unit representation.

So, using the "UTF8toUnicode" transformation in most language libraries will produce UTF-16, which is essentially UCS-2.  And simply extracting the 16-bit characters from an Objective-C string will accomplish the same thing.

In other words, the solution has been staring you in the face all along.

Comment: `UTF8toUnicode` is not a function name that makes any sense, since UTF-8 is already Unicode. This sounds like some dumb Microsoft bug to me.

Comment: I was using it as a generic term.  Most language libraries refer to UTF-16 as "Unicode".

Comment: I've been working with Unicode for more than a decade as well, and "Unicode" is how Java referred to UTF-16 originally.  When Unicode was originally invented UTF-32 didn't exist, for all intents and purposes, and, whether it was "correct" or not, "Unicode" and "UTF-16" were treated as interchangeable terms.

Answer (score 0):

UCS-2 is not a valid Unicode encoding.  UTF-8 is.

It is therefore impossible to convert UTF-8 into UCS-2 — and indeed, also the reverse.

UCS-2 is dead, ancient history.  Let it rot in peace.

Comment: While it is true that not all UTF-8 strings can be converted to UCS-2, in practice many can. Furthermore, a lot of systems and string libraries support several methods for handling characters that cannot be converted to a different encoding. It isn't possible either to convert all UTF-8 strings to ISO-8859-1, yet it is required and done very often in practice. You're a bit harsh in your answer.

Comment: @Codo: You make a good point that it just as little sense to convert UTF-8 to Latin1 as it does to convert UTF-8 to UCS-2, since neither is a valid Unicode encoding. However, all Latin1 code points can be represented as valid UTF-8.  This is not true with UCS-2.  It is not a symmetric situation. I cannot see that the Apple ioS filesystem uses UCS-2 anyway. It seems to use UTF-16 in a bastard not-quite-NFD form. The question betrays fuzzy thinking unclear on the concept of Unicode.

Comment: I think you are way out of point. What I intend to do is to find out how to convert to UCS-2 from UTF-8. And there are still many ways doing that in C# or other languages.

Comment: @Joshua Oh really? Then please convert the UTF-8 byte sequence "\xF0\x9F\x92\xA9" into UCS-2. Note the name of that code point. Good luck, and have a nice day.